# Read DateTime from CSV values

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a CSV file as follows:

```
Date,Minimum,Maximum
03-01-2020,37.23,37.34
10-01-2020,36.78,37.54
```

I used Matlab's 2019b readtable to load the data to Matlab:

```
data = readtable('data.csv', 'DatetimeType', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

But I get the following error:

```
Expected input to match one of these values:

'datetime', 'text'

The input, 'dd-mm-yyyy', did not match any of the valid values.
```

If I simply use:

```
data = readtable('data.csv')
```

I get the data:

```
{'03-01-2020'}    37.23    37.34    36.63    36.88     5519 
{'10-01-2020'}    36.78    37.54    36.64    37.41     9093
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The function is not defined to take `'dd-mm-yyyy'` as a valid value. Please read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `readtable()` can handle custom formats, but you can convert it manually:

```matlab
data = readtable('data.csv');
data.Date = datetime(data.Date, 'format', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
class(data.Date)

% ans =
%
%     'datetime'
```